# Ask Excel to automatically update after I change the external sources

Tags: excel, external-links

I am using R to output some tables, in the format of CSV. I also have another spreadsheet (xlsx) file to get numbers from those csv files and show the graphs (I could have used R to plot, but due to some documentation requirement, I have to use excel to do graphing).

However, every time when I replace the csv files, with the exactly the same file name and the format, Excel is not able to update the external link automatically. It keeps saying it just cannot update the link. When I look at "Edit Links", excel can open all external sources correctly, but it just cannot recognize the replaced files.

I am not very familiar with VBA, so I prefer a solution without writing some extra codes? Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful if your description was a little more technical. Can you tell us what Excel version, how you established the connection (Data > Get External Data > Text File?), the exact error message and location of the csv (e.g., on a network share).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works if I replace the underlying csv files and use "Open Sources" to open each of these new csv files. Then the graph will automatically update.